# DateTime型のNULL更新について

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**実行環境**
■ Laravel : 5.7
■ PHP : 7.2

**実現したいこと:**
モデルDateTime型のNULL更新したいのですが、やり方よくわかりません。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
formのinputに空に変更で更新する時に、
何故か現在時刻に自動更新している。

**該当のソースコード**
現在のモデルの内容

```
/?php
namespace /**省略**/
class Job extends Model {

    /**
     * @var キャスト （toArray、toJson用）
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'visit_date' => 'date:Y-m-d',
        'job_start' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i',
        'job_end' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i',
    ];

    /**
     * @var date 時間フォーマット表示
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'visit_date', 
        'job_start',
        'job_end',
    ];

    // $fillableに指定したもの以外は入らない（save、update、fill）
    protected $fillable = [
        /**省略**/
        'visit_date', 
        'job_start',
        'job_end',
        /**省略**/
    ];

    /**他のFUNCTIONは無関係なので省略**/

    /**
     *　ミューテター
     *　job_start の　設定
     * @param  string  $value ($valueのフォーマットは 'Y:m:d H:i')
     * @return void
     */
    public function setJobStartAttribute($value) {
        if($value !== null){
            //$valueのフォーマットは 'Y:m:d H:i'
            //Carbon で正常のフォーマットに変更する？
            $value = (new Carbon($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        //null ならそのまま？
        $this->attributes['job_start'] = $value;
    }

    /**
     *　ミューテター
     *　job_start の　取得
     * @param  string  $value ($valueのフォーマットは 'Y:m:d H:i')
     * @return void
     */
    public function getJobStartAttribute($value) {
        return (new Carbon($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    }

}
```

**関連のマイグレーション**

```
Schema::create('jobs', function(Blueprint $table)
{
/**省略**/
$table->dateTime('job_start')->nullable();
$table->dateTime('job_end')->nullable();
});
```

---

試したこと1

```
public function edit($id, Request $request){
 $job = Job::findOrFail($id);
 $job->job_start = null;
 $job->save();
}
```

試したこと2

```
public function update($id, Request $request){
 $job = Job::findOrFail($id);
 //input内容のjob_startは空です
 $job->fill( $request->input() );
 $job->save();
}
```

両方とも何故かjob_startが現在時刻に更新しています。

同じ質問をteratailにも投稿しています。
https://teratail.com/questions/209084

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/209084

Comment: 実際のテーブルの構造を追記していただくことは可能ですか？

Comment: マイグレーションでは駄目ですか？
実際に関連に使うカラムの所を表示しでいます。

Comment: マイグレーションでは設定していないデフォルトの数値や自動プロパティ等がフレームワークのバージョンとMySQLのバージョンの組み合わせによって変わる可能性があるので実際の構造があるとより回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://teratail.com/questions/209084
で解決しました。

多分、laravelのsave時には、getJobStartAttributeを通しています。
以下の通りに変更したら、解決しました。

```
public function getJobStartAttribute($value) {
    if ($value !== null) {
       return (new Carbon($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    }
    return $value;
}
```